# ¿Cómo migrar un proyecto de visual studio a una versión más antigua?

Tags: visual-studio

Mi problema es, que debido a la lentitud de visual studio 2015 y nuevas versiones en comparación con 2008 quiero pasar mis nuevos proyectos a la antigua versión de visual studio. El problema que se me presenta es que al abrirlo no puedo porque me pone:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera de mover mis nuevos proyectos a la version antigua de visual studio 2008, es decir, que el fichero `.sln` funcione con la versión antigua de visual studio 2008?

Comment: Lentitud? el problema sera otro? Igual creo que la mejor solucion es crear una solucion en blanco e ir copiando todos los archivos que necesites.

Comment: Yo lo he hecho abriendo el archivo .sln con notepad++ ahi viene la versión solo la cambio y funciona abrirlo

Comment: Sospecho que te traerá problemas al configurar manualmente el sln, lo mas recomendable sería copiar tu código a la versión 2008

Comment: si pero pierdo la configuración etc... por eso preguntaba si habia alguna manera viable de pasarlo aunk el problema estará igualmente si paso a una versión antigua porque a lo mejor la configuración de 2015 no es valida para 2008.